# python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent (Tab, in an inferior python mode shell) completes "__PYTHON_EL_eval_file"

Tags: python, completion, ipython, inferior-python-mode

On Emacs 29, Python 3.11.3, IPython 8.13.2

A strange behavior seems to have recently started. When opening a python shell with `run-python` and then `python-shell-send-buffer` or `python-shell-send-file` Tab completion inserts the command that is sent to the shell to send the buffer or file. Something like:

`__PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/var/folders/bq/8rm29p3528bggkl1dy36h4mh0000gn/T/pySXmI6k", "/var/folders/bq/8rm29p3528bggkl1dy36h4mh0000gn/T/pySXmI6k", True))`

`completion-at-point-fuction` is set to `(python-shell-completion-at-point comint-completion-at-point t)`.

This happens with `python-mode` or `python.el` and using both python3 or ipython3 for the inferior python mode.

How can I prevent this from happening?

See below:

Before pressing tab:
[image]

After pressing tab:
[image]

Interestingly, it *does* complete "Image". But it adds the file load command before the completed text.

Comment: Same problem here with, didnt find a fix yet.

Comment: Perhaps we can debug this together. What does your Python dev environment consist of? For me, it's lsp-mode with pyright, python-mode, pyvenv. For completions I use company and company-box.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround.
I wish I better understood where this problem stems from though.

```
(defun my-python-completion-filter (completions)
  "Filter out the unwanted '__PYTHON_EL' from COMPLETIONS."
  (cl-remove-if (lambda (completion) (string-match-p "__PYTHON_EL" completion))
                completions))

(advice-add 'python-shell-completion-get-completions :filter-return #'my-python-completion-filter)
```

Comment: This is a decent work-around; just remove the weird bit from the completions list. I will give it a try.